# How to encrypt strings in RSA (exercise)

Tags: encryption, rsa

I'm trying to solve a crypto RSA problem from my last exam in a clean way, but I'm stuck in the last step...

First of all, we are using an alphabet with 27 characters (i.e. spanish alphabet: A-Z + Ñ). We will code each char as A=0, B=1, ..., N=13, Ñ=14, O=15, ..., Y=25, Z=26.

We have `d=7`, `n=33`, `e=3`.

As 27<sup>1</sup> < 33 < 27<sup>2</sup> we can split our message in blocks of 1 character each.

We want to encrypt the string **NIÑO**, so:

- N → 13<sup>7</sup> mod 33 = 7 → H
- I → 8<sup>7</sup> mod 33 = 2 → C
- Ñ → 14<sup>7</sup> mod 33 = 20 → T
- O → 15<sup>7</sup> mod 33 = 27 → **¿?**

Comment: This is just zero based indexing. If C = 2 then A = 0. As Ñ is 14 then 27 must be...Oh, it's a joke, it's out of range of the alphabet. In that case the outcome is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the problem statement does not allow to encode the whole ciphertext as letters. Options includes writing the ciphertext as HCT27 or 7 2 20 27 or 07022027, and explain why.

Note: in standard expositions of RSA, encryption uses exponent `e`, not `d` as in the proposed solution. But with this small `n` it turns out that makes no difference in the result. In my view, using such a small `n` in RSA exercises is ill-advised from a pedagogical standpoint, especially with no reminder that for RSA to be secure, a necessary condition is that `n` has hundreds decimal digits.

Comment: Ooops! You're right, my fault :-). Thanks!